# Nested attributes in form not visible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, nested-attributes, formtastic

I'm likely missing something simple, but I've tried a number of things to no avail. 
I need to be able to edit an existing track (using ActiveAdmin) and save the record updating its exclusivity status.

I have a `Tracks` model

```
#app/models/track.rb:

  has_many :exclusivities, class_name: 'Exclusivity', dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exclusivities

  attr_accessible :exclusivities_attributes

  #whether or not track is exclusive [boolean]
  attr_accessible :exclusive

  #whether or not track is fully exclusive and should be pulled off the front end [boolean]
  attr_accessible :full_exclusivity
```

and I just created an `Exclusivity` model.

```
#app/models/exclusivity.rb    

  belongs_to :track
  attr_accessible :end_date, :industry, :track_id, :notes, :staff_notes
```

and my form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:manage, @track], html: {data: {secondary:true}} do |f| %>

a bunch of inputs.....

<%= f.inputs "Track Exclusivity", class:'inputs align-left' do %>
  <%= f.input :exclusive %>
  <%= f.input :full_exclusivity,
  label: "Fully Exclusive" %>
  <%= f.fields_for :exclusivities do %>
    <%= f.input :notes %> 
    <%= f.input :staff_notes %> 
    <%= f.input :industry %> 
    <%= f.input :end_date, as: :date_picker %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I go to edit a track, the Track attrs are there, but the nested (Exclusivity attrs) are not (I can check track's exclusive and full_exclusivity checkboxes)

I've also tried using `semantic_fields_for` and `f.inputs :for => exclusivities`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass your form builder to the fields_for block.

```
<%= f.inputs "Track Exclusivity", class:'inputs align-left' do %>
  <%= f.input :exclusive %>
  <%= f.input :full_exclusivity,
  label: "Fully Exclusive" %>
  <%= f.fields_for :exclusivities do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.input :notes %> 
    <%= ff.input :staff_notes %> 
    <%= ff.input :industry %> 
    <%= ff.input :end_date, as: :date_picker %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks man. You're right, I overlooked that! That said, still, when I go to edit (using activeAdmin) those associated fields are still not avail.

Comment: Hi glad you solved your issue. I was going to suggest that you ensure that your objects were not nil but didn't want to be pedantic since your original since you mentioned "editing" I assumed the exclusivities were already created. But yes nil associated objects are usually the culprit and gets you every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
  ...
  <%= person_form.fields_for :projects do |project_fields| %>
    <% if project_fields.object.active? %>
      Name: <%= project_fields.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

from http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue was this: the form fields weren't showing up if the exclusivity attributes of a track were empty. So I automatically build the associated attrs as soon as you hit the edit controller, using this code. Does the trick!

```
 def edit
   @track = Track.includes(:licenses).find(params[:id])
      if @track.exclusivities.empty?
        @track.exclusivities.build
      end
    @track.save
 end
```